# Filter to a specific folder when selecting assets to choose from

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor

In my custom editor I have an ObjectField to assign a sprite:

```
spell.icon = (Sprite)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Icon", spell.icon, typeof(Sprite), false);
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is that when I go to select a Sprite, it pulls up everything from my project.

Is there a way to filter this down to a specific folder?

[image: Image Example]]

Comment: Are you sure all the sprites have different label than "Icon"?

Comment: @SaadAnees what are you talking about? ^^

Comment: Afaik not directly but you would have to implement it yourself e.g. using [EditorGUIUtility.ShowObjectPicker](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUIUtility.ShowObjectPicker.html) with a custom `searchFilter` pointing to your directory